# explain why "results" in 3 different Position have different output?

Tags: python

```
#Position1: 
#results=[]
for i in range(2):
    #Position2:
    results=[]
    for j in range(3):
        #Position3:
        #results=[]
        results.append(i+j)
print(results)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please explain in more detail what you're having issues with. Include examples/expected output. This question makes no sense as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you do `results=[]` you're overwriting the variable. Any previous results that were saved in it are discarded.

If you do it before all the loops, the final contents will come from all the loop iterations.

If you do it inside any loop, then you throw away all the results from previous iterations of that loop. The final value will just be from the last iteration of that loop.

If you do it in the innermost loop, you just get the last value from all the iterations.

Answer (score 1):

It is different because `results=[]` simply re-initiates the list to an empty list. So all the data stored in it is erased as soon as your code executes `results=[]`. This depends on the position where you initialize this list. All your three positions are at different levels of for loops and hence the output is different.

The *position 1* will store all the output of both `for` loops which means for `i = 0`, `j = 0, 1, 2` and then `i = 1`, `j = 0, 1, 2`

The *position 2* will re-initialize the list twice because your outer loop runs twice. So it will store the data corresponding to `i = 1` and `j = 0, 1, 2` because the list for `i = 0` will be over-written.

The *position 3* will re-initialize the list six times because your outer loop runs twice and your inner loop runs thrice (thrice for each iteration of the outer loop).

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of what is happening can be seen in the following loop:

```
for i in range(2):
    r = []
    print(f'r == {r} before append in iteration {i+1}')
    r.append(i)
    print(f'r == {r} after iteration {i+1}') 

# OUTPUT
# r == [] before append in iteration 1
# r == [0] after append in iteration 1
# r == [] before append in iteration 2
# r == [1] after append in iteration 2
```

Instead of `r` ending up as `[0, 1]`, it ends up as `[1]` because you can see that after the first iteration, you reset `r` to an empty list `[]` before you append the next value of `i`.